# Selectize.js: get focus on mousedown click

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, selectize.js

Can't get focus on input dynamically added item with selectize plugin. Here is code
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H77DZ/6/)

[selectize.js plugin](http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.selectize').selectize({
    render: {
        option: function(item){
            if (item.text === 'add-new-sidebar'){
                return '<div class="fw-backend-add-new-sidebar">' +
                    '<span class="input_legend">New Sidebar</span>' +
                    '<input type="text" id="add_new_sidebar_name">'+
                    '<input type="button" class="button" value="Add" id="add_new_sidebar_submit">'+
                    '</div>'
            }
            return '<div class="selectize-item">' + item.text + '</div>';

        }
    },
    onChange: function(item){

    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what exactly you mean by not being able to get focus on input. There are [callbacks](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md) that handle that though.

To take any action whenever input gains or loses focus you need to pass `onFocus` and `onBlur` callbacks in the options. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H77DZ/7/) based on the one you provided does that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery('.selectize').selectize({
    // ... taking out original code for brevity
    onFocus: function () {
        // control has gained focus
    },
    onBlur: function () {
        // control has lost focus
    }    
  });
});
```

It's worth to mention that the above interface works only starting Selectize 0.12.0

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you. Full list of events can be found here https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/usage.md